# WCF Exception thrown when debugging application that calls service

Tags: .net, web-services, wcf, debugging

**UPDATE:** *We have narrowed the problem down to occurring after migrating this specific service from a Windows 2003 server to a Windows 2008 server.  If we copy the files back to the Windows 2003 server and pull a reference from there, we can debug locally again.  Are there any updates required in the config file when moving from 2003 to 2008?*

We have a number of IIS hosted WCF services.  One service is behaving differently than any of our other services.  There are two specific differences that I think point to the problem, but after exhaustive Googling and surfing other answers on Stack, I still can't find it.  The first difference is that this service prompts for a username and password when trying to add a Service Reference in Visual Studio (none of our other services do this).  The second is that when we debug (locally) any of our web applications that call this service we get an error that says, *"The HTTP request is unauthorized with client authentication scheme 'Negotiate'. The authentication header received from the server was 'Negotiate,NTLM'."*  The service still works as expected when called from any of our websites that are deployed to our web servers.  Because this is a user authentication service, it prevents any debugging activities.

I've checked the Authentication and Authorization settings in IIS for this service against another service that is behaving "correctly", (ie - not prompting for credentials when adding a service reference and working when we debug an application that calls it).  They all match up.  Also, compared the binding, client and behaviors sections in the web.config for both the service and the website calling the service and they seem to be in sync.  The service worked fine in the past and according to our ops team and the rest of the developers "Nothing has changed".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you checked that delegations are trusted by all machines your service call hops through? (Active Directory setting)

[image]

Comment: I haven't, but since it works when running the website from any of our web servers (as opposed to when I'm debugging the website locally) I don't know that there are any different machines involved.

Comment: It is worthwhile to check. The service server may be trusting the delegation from the web server, but not your development machine. Without knowing all the details of your setup, this is my best guess.

Comment: Where would I check this?

Comment: In Active Directory Users and Computer (if you don't have this on your Windows, Google to see how to add), search for your machine names.

Comment: If this was the issue, wouldn't the other services (hosted on the same box) present the username and password challenge as well?

Comment: They would (if you use the same machine for development, the same server for web, the same server for all services), that was why I said I did not know all the details of your setup.